# authentication and authorization for Reactivemongo

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo

I'm using play 2.3 + reactivemongo 
I need to integrate a system of authentication and authorization to my project.

What options exist of plugins or modules for reactivemongo?

Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 2):

I recommend,
[Play Silhouette](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette). It is database agnostic, requires you to write the interface layer to Mongo, but the API is non-blocking (methods return Future), so you can use Reactive Mongo easily.